# SSLError using flask_dance for OAuth2

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, oauth, python-requests

I am trying to connect to a OAuth2-Provider using flask_dance. The provider has a self-signed certificate. When I sent `request.post(***, verify=False)` directly everything works fine. However when I use  `OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint()` from `flask_dance.consumer` I always get the following error.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='***', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /as/token.oauth2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Is there a way to set `verify=false` globally for all requests called from a script or to set `verify=false` for the whole `OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint()`. Also a solution could be to add an exception for the cert. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should install the certificate in the local keystore. This way you also keep the connection ‘safer’ than not verifying the certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint() additional Parameters can be set e.g. in the `token_url_params`. This way it will passed through to the flask_dance requests
from flask import Flask
from flask_dance.consumer import OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint

```
app = Flask(__name__)
example_blueprint = OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint(
  "oauth-example", __name__,
  client_id="my-key-here",
  client_secret="my-secret-here",
  base_url="https://oauth-example.com",
  token_url="https://oauth-example.com/login/access_token",
  authorization_url="https://oauth-example.com/login/authorize",
  token_url_params=dict(verify=False)
)
app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint, url_prefix="/login")
```